# Proof that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(1-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega})e^{-\beta\hbar\omega j}=1$

Tags: probability, integration, summation

I need to show that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(1-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega})e^{-\beta\hbar\omega j}=1$, for $\beta,\,\hbar,\,\omega\,\in\,\mathbb{R}$, given that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}p_{j}=1$, $p_{j}=(1-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega})e^{-\beta\hbar\omega j}$.

I initially tried to integrate directly by doing
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-\beta\hbar\omega j}-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega(j+1)})dj=1$$
but the result diverges, since there is no solution
$$\frac{1-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}}{\beta\hbar\omega}\neq1\text{.}$$

Another try has been expanded:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(e^{-\beta\hbar\omega j}-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega(j+1)})=1$$
$$(1-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}+e^{-\beta\hbar\omega}-e^{-2\beta\hbar\omega}+e^{-2\beta\hbar\omega}-e^{-3\beta\hbar\omega}+...+e^{-\beta\hbar\omega\infty}-e^{-\beta\hbar\omega(\infty+1)})=1\text{.}$$
As the values of $e$ ​​decrease as $j \to \infty$, $e^{-\alpha\infty}=0$ and $e^{-\alpha(\infty+1)}=e^{-\alpha\infty}=0$,
$$(1-e^{-3\beta\hbar\omega})=1\text{,}$$
In power series,
$$1-1+3\beta\hbar\omega-\frac{(3\beta\hbar\omega)^{2}}{2}+\frac{(3\beta\hbar\omega)^{3}}{6}-...=1\text{.}$$
Disregarding the most distant terms of the series,
$$-\frac{(3\beta\hbar\omega)^{2}}{2}+\frac{(3\beta\hbar\omega)^{3}}{6}=1\text{.}$$
This is obviously not right. Any suggestions on what I should do, or any notable errors along the way?

Comment: Why are you using integrals and not exploiting the geometric series property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega} \right)e^{-\beta \hbar \omega j} = \left(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega} \right) \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (e^{-\beta \hbar \omega j}) $$

(We can always factor out terms that don't depend on $j$. Now recall that

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^j = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

And that $x^{uv} = (x^u)^v$. So we now have that:

$$  \left(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega} \right) \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (e^{-\beta \hbar \omega j}) = \left(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega} \right) \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (e^{-\beta \hbar \omega})^j = \left(1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega} \right)  \frac{1}{1 - e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}} $$

And clearly that RHS is equal to 1.